# Construction of Hadamard Matrices of Order $n!$

Tags: matrices, reference-request, hadamard-matrices

I'm trying to get a hand on Hadamard matrices of order $n!$, with $n>3$. [Payley's construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley_construction) says that there is a Hadamard matrix for $q+1$, with $q$ being a prime power.
Since
$$
n!-1 \bmod 4 = 3
$$
[construction 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley_construction#Paley_construction_I)  has to be chosen:

> If $q$ is congruent to $3 (\bmod 4)$ [and $Q$ is the corresponding [Jacobsthal matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobsthal_matrix#Quadratic_character_and_Jacobsthal_matrix)] then
>   $$    H=I+\begin{bmatrix} 0 & j^T\\ -j & Q\end{bmatrix} $$
>   is a Hadamard matrix of size $q + 1$. Here $j$ is the all-1 column vector of length $q$ and $I$ is the $(q+1)×(q+1)$ identity matrix. The matrix $H$ is a skew Hadamard matrix, which means it satisfies $H+H^T = 2I$.

The problem is that the number of primes among $n!-1$ is restricted (see [A002982](http://oeis.org/A002982)). I checked the values of [$n!-1$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28n%29!-1%29) given by Wolfram|Alpha w.r.t. be a prime power, without success, so Payley's construction won't work for all $n$.

> Is there a general way to get the matrices, or is it case by case different?
>
> I haven't yet looked into Williamson's construction nor Turyn type constructions. Would it be worth a closer look (sure it would, but) concerning my problem? **Where can I find their constructions?**

PS for the interested reader: I've found a nice compilation of Hadamard matrices here: http://neilsloane.com/hadamard/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think a general construction for Hadamard matrices of order $n!$ is known. The knowledge about general construction methods for Hadamard matrices is quite sparse, the basic ones (see also the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix)) are:

1) If $n$ is a multiple of $4$ such that $n-1$ is a prime power or $n/2 - 1$ is a prime power $\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, then there exists a Hadamard Matrix of order $n$ (Paley).

2) If $n$ is a multiple of $4$ such that there exists a Hadamard Matrix of order $n/2$, then there exists a Hadamard Matrix of order $n$ (Sylvester).

The Hadamard conjecture states that for all multiples $n$ of $4$ there is a Hadamard matrix of order $n$.
The above constructions do not cover all these $n$, the smallest case not covered is $n = 92$.
There are more specialized constructions and a few computer constructions, such that the smallest open case is $n = 668$ nowadays.

EDIT:

I have just checked that for $n\in\{13,26,44,52,63,67,70,77,85\}$ a Hadamard matrix of order $n!$ cannot be constructed only by a combination of the Paley/Sylvester construction above. So in these cases, one had to check more specialized constructions like Williamsons' one.

Comment: +1 thanks. What about Williamson and Turyn? Do you know how they work?...I see

Comment: Not really. But my impression is that it is not so easy to see for which orders those constructions work.

Comment: thanks again... what was the max imum number you checked?

Comment: your're welcome! I've checked n! for n up to 100...

Comment: How did do it and/or what's the construction for $n=88$?

Comment: Construct order $88! / 2^{31}$ by Paley ($88! / 2^{31} - 1$ is prime) and then apply Sylvester 31 times.